# A 6 DOF robot arm URDF file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all.

I just want to play a bit with Move it in Hydro. I have been seeking for URDF files that can be load it into `moveit_setup_assistant` However, I have found some files with the extension of `.urdf.xacro` and I can not simply load it with `moveit_setup_assistant`. Further on, I have tried to convert `.urdf.xacro` to `.urdf` with the following command: `rosrun xacro xacro.py file.urdf.xacro -o file.urdf` But without success, the `file.urdf` is empty.

I know I can start creating my own .urdf file, but at this moment I just want to play with move it.

```
I would like to ask if some wants to share a  6DOF urdf robot arm manipulator with end effector file
```

In advance thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187018/a-6-dof-robot-arm-urdf-file/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2014-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

rosrun xacro xacro.py should work fine.

Please post the output of the command. Try the command by specifying the absolute path of the urdf.xacro file.

Even `rosrun xacro xacro.py file.urdf.xacro > file.urdf` should work.

If you want a urdf, you can find it under jaco_description/urdf/gazebo

https://github.com/ksatyaki/JacoROS

Have a great day!
Chittaranjan

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2014-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2014-07-21**:
Hi, thank you very much for your answer, I will try your suggestions asap, and you too have a great day :)

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2014-07-21**:
DEPRECATED IN HYDRO:
The  tag should be prepended with 'xacro' if that is the intended use
of it, such as <xacro:include ...>. Use the following script to fix incorrect
xacro includes:
sed -i 's/<include/<xacro:include/g' `find . -iname *.xacro`
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/hydro/share/xacro/xacro.py", line 60, in 
xacro.main()
File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/**init**.py", line 657, in main
process_includes(doc, os.path.dirname(args[0]))
File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/**init**.py", line 245, in process_includes
filename_spec = eval_text(elt.getAttribute('filename'), {})
File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/**init**.py", line 476, in eval_text
results.append(handle_extension(lex.next()[1][2:-1]))
File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/**init**.py", line 464, in handle_extension
return eval_extension("$(%s)" % s)
File "/opt/ros/

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2014-07-21**:
thats the output of the command, the fact is that moveit_setup_assistant cant load the urdf file due to is invalid format.

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2014-07-21**:
Well, I could have load in moveit the urdf file from jacoROS, do you know a nice site where they explain how to create the links, joints and effector in kind of open CAD?

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-21**:
I think that error is because the urdf is outdated.
I am sorry, I know nothing about gazebo. Search for tutorials.